# How to convert dataframe into float type?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe column into a float type. I have tried following snippet

```
m_df = pd.read_csv(input_file,nrows=1,header=None,skiprows=4)
m1=m_df.ix[:,1:1]
```

This snippet just returns me the number in first column. How can I turn it into float?

[I am new to python/numpy]

Comment: make use of  `astype()` method...i.e `m_df['ix']=m_df['ix'].astype(float)` or `m1=m_df.ix[:,1:1].astype(float)`

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) might be helpful too.